# Meaning of the word "award" in a stanza of Byron's "The Bride of Abydos"

Tags: meaning, poetry, lord-byron, the-bride-of-abydos

I am reading a poem by Lord Byron: *The Bride of Abydos* and I am unsure about the meaning of the word **award** in Canto I, stanza 3, quoted below. Does it mean a sum of money such as a tip or does it have another meaning?

> “Let the chamber be cleared.” – the train disappeared –
> “Now call me the chief of the Haram guard –”
> With Giaffir is none but his only son,
> And the Nubian awaiting the sire’s **award**. (35)
> “Haroun – when all the crowd that wait
> Are passed beyond the outer gate,
> (Woe to the head whose eye beheld
> My child Zuleika’s face unveiled!)
> Hence, lead my daughter from her tower – (40)
> Her fate is fixed this very hour;
> Yet not to her repeat my thought –
> By me alone be duty taught!”

[Full poem here](http://www.newsteadabbeybyronsociety.org/works/downloads/turk_3.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely using the [archaic meaning of "award"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/award) "decision after consideration". That is, the Harem guard is waiting for Giaffir's decision.